# Need better current datetime syntax

Tags: sql-server-2008, datetime

This is current/old Access query I inherited.Need to retrieve the past year Case log. How can I write a better current date in Where clause?

```
    Select (ID,DateLog,TimeLog)
    From tblActiveCase
    WHERE (((DatePart("yyyy",[DateLog])) Between DatePart("yyyy",Now())-1 And           
     DatePart("yyyy",Now())))
```

--My new StoredProc

```
    Select (ID,DateLog,TimeLog)
    From tblActiveCase
    WHERE DateLog <= DATEADD(YEAR, -1, GETDATE())
```

is there a better way to write it?

Comment: Clarify: I need to get current date, to exactly 1 year ago.

Comment: I think you need `>=`, not `<=`. If the date in the database is a DateTime then it would probably be best to set the time to 00:00:00, otherwise you would miss records created in the morning one year ago if your query was run in the afternoon.

Comment: Can you clarify if you mean it is MS Access *or* SQL Server, the latter being what you have tagged your question with.

Comment: Thank you for all your help. My problem was using wrong operator. And yes this is an Access migration/rewrite to sql 2008. I will have more questions soon. This place gives great resolutions

Comment: The original query seems to be doing a comparison of `year of DateLog BETWEEN (year of now) -1 AND (year of now)`.  If you asked for logs today, it would return anything from 2013-01-01 to 2014-12-31 (if I remember my Access correctly).  Your replacement instead asks for the logs for the trailing year (now minus 1 year), so if you asked for logs today 2014-10-01, you would get logs from 2013-10-01 to 2014-10-01.  These are much different ranges, is that what you really want?

Comment: @ToriT. In your questions in future, please mention that you are upgrading from Access to SQL Server. It will be much easier to answer your questions with that information.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @date date
set @date = DATEADD(YEAR, -1, GETDATE())

    Select (ID,DateLog,TimeLog)
        From tblActiveCase
        WHERE DateLog >= @date
```

Comment: Can you use `DECLARE` in Access? I looked for it, but could find no such thing.

Comment: oh! it was taged SQL-SERVER-2008 and also mention a stored procedure. Now I'm not sure what op was talking about

Comment: I've added a comment asking the OP for clarification. It is so much easier with SQL Server.

Comment: well, I didn't know that access can have stored procedures. If this was the case, @date need to be pass as a (new) parameter

Comment: it seems to be a migration from access to sql 2008 (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26149073/need-to-simplify)